# Flutter SVG delay when rendering

Tags: flutter, svg, rendering

I display in row both an image as an SVG file and a text.

For some reason, the svg image renders slower than the rest of the screen, leading to a delay which isn't good for the user experience.

Is this delay normal ? What could I do so that the whole screen renders at the same time ?

```dart
Row(
   mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: [
          SvgPicture.asset(
            'lib/assets/muslim_coloc_logo.svg',
            height: 40.0,
            width: 40.0,
          ),
          SizedBox(width: 2.0,),
          RichText(
            text: TextSpan(children: [
              TextSpan(
                text: 'uslim',
                style: MC_titleWhite,
              ),
              TextSpan(
                text: 'Coloc',
                style: MC_titleWhite50,
              ),
            ]),
          ),
        ],
      ),
```

[image]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

UPDATE:

```dart
  await precachePicture(
    ExactAssetPicture(SvgPicture.svgStringDecoderBuilder, 'assets/my_icon.svg'),
    null,
  );
```

You can use a PreCachePicture, it works for me:

```
Future.wait([
  precachePicture(
    ExactAssetPicture(SvgPicture.svgStringDecoder, 'assets/my_icon.svg'),
    null,
  ),
  precachePicture(
    ExactAssetPicture(SvgPicture.svgStringDecoder, 'assets/my_asset.svg'),
    null,
  ),
]);
```

You need to do it in a previous screen widget, like in your **main**, as example

Answer (score 1):

`precachePicture` has been deprecated to cache the SVG image, we can you `SvgAssetLoader` as alternative.

```
void main() async {
  ImageUtils.svgPrecacheImage();
  runApp(const MyApp());
}
```

Specify all assets images in utils class.

```
 class ImageUtils {
    
      static const String imageHistory = 'assets/images/ic_history.svg';
      static const String imageShared = 'assets/images/ic_shared.svg';
      static const String imageMap = 'assets/images/ic_maps.svg';
    
    
     static void svgPrecacheImage() {

        const cacheSvgImages = [  /// Specify the all the svg image to cache 
          ImageUtils.imageHistory,
          ImageUtils.imageShared,
          ImageUtils.imageMap,
        ];
    
        for (String element in cacheSvgImages) {
          var loader = SvgAssetLoader(element);
          svg.cache
              .putIfAbsent(loader.cacheKey(null), () => loader.loadBytes(null));
        }

      }
    
    }
```