# How to improve listview perfomance?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am new in flutter and was working on it for a while, but I still cant understand why does my listview lag... I am trying to build mobile web version, you can check it here: https://koza-nostra-b2b.web.app/#/

Here is my full code:

```
import 'package:auto_size_text/auto_size_text.dart';
import 'package:card_swiper/card_swiper.dart';
import 'package:delayed_display/delayed_display.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:flutter_svg/svg.dart';
import 'package:url_launcher/url_launcher.dart';

final List<String> homePageImgs = [
  "assets/png/Home/Rectangle 154.png",
  "assets/png/Home/Rectangle 143.png",
  "assets/png/Home/Rectangle 142.png",
];

final List<AdvBox> advBoxItems = [
  AdvBox(
      svg: 'assets/svg/Home/Adv1.svg',
      title: 'Более 25 SKU',
      description: 'Самый большой выбор козьих сыров'),
  AdvBox(
      svg: 'assets/svg/Home/Adv2.svg',
      title: 'Для ресторанов',
      description: 'Сыры для сырных тарелок, пиццы, салатов, жарки'),
  AdvBox(
      svg: 'assets/svg/Home/Adv3.svg',
      title: 'Экопродукт',
      description: 'Самые натуральные корма для животных'),
  AdvBox(
      svg: 'assets/svg/Home/Adv4.svg',
      title: 'Вся документация',
      description:
          'Полный комплект документов в соответствии с законодательством'),
  AdvBox(
      svg: 'assets/svg/Home/Adv5.svg',
      title: 'Контроль качества',
      description:
          'На ферме внедрена система контроля качества от поля до прилавка'),
];

class AdvBox {
  final String svg;
  final String title;
  final String description;

  AdvBox({
    Key? key,
    required this.svg,
    required this.title,
    required this.description,
  });
}

class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyHomePage({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final List<Widget> pageitems = [
      _svgOnTop(context),
      _textBlock(
          'Добро пожаловать на сайт «Коза Ностра» для оптовых продаж. Мы поставляем сыры и молочную продукцию в рестораны, кафе, отели, а также во все категории магазинов розничной торговли и e-commerce.',
          const EdgeInsets.only(left: 20, right: 20, top: 10, bottom: 40)),
      _gallerySwiper(context),
      _textBlock(
          'На ферме «КОЗА НОСТРА» разводят племенных коз англо-нубийской и зааненской пород и производят сыры по оригинальным рецептам европейских стран из козьего молока - мягкие сыры, твердые и полутвердые, с белой благородной плесенью и в древесной золе, с натуральным трюфелем и паприкой.',
          const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20)),
      _wideBlock(
        "НАГРАДЫ КОЗА НОСТРА",
        "Текст о том как у фермы много наград и достижений",
        'assets/svg/Home/logo Awards.svg',
        BoxDecoration(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30),
          color: Colors.white,
          border: Border.all(width: 2, color: const Color(0xFFAD8A6E)),
        ),
        context,
      ),
      _textBlock(
          'У нас самый большой выбор козьих сыров — твердые и полутвердые, мягкие, в белой благородной плесени и древесной золе, с натуральным трюфелем и паприкой и многие другие. Наше производство – это сочетание ручного труда и современных высоких технологий сыроварения. \n\nСыроваренный цех оснащен самым современным оборудованием. Одно из главных условий создания отличного выдержанного сыра – процесс его вызревания, по-французски — аффинаж. В хозяйстве построена уникальная пещера для созревания сыров длительной выдержки.',
          const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20)),
      _horizontalScroller(),
      _textBlock(
        'Построить ферму основателей хозяйства подвигло желание создавать для людей хорошие и качественные сыры. В Европе сыр является неотъемлемой частью рациона питания. Свежий, теплый, хрустящий багет с сыром — это вкусный и питательный завтрак. \n\nСыр – прекрасное дополнение к ужину и питательный здоровый десерт. Люди часто собираются в компании за бутылочкой хорошего вина с сырной тарелкой. Не бойтесь ошибиться с выбором, при заказе мы свяжемся с вами, проконсультируем и даже вышлем в подарок наш дегустационный набор.',
        const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20),
      ),
      _wideBlock(
        "ДОСТАВКА И ОПЛАТА",
        "Как работает наша доставка",
        'assets/svg/Home/Delivery.svg',
        BoxDecoration(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30),
          color: const Color(0xFFECD5B3),
        ),
        context,
      ),
      _allLinksBox(context),
    ];


    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: const Color(0xFFECD5B3),
      body: Stack(
        alignment: AlignmentDirectional.topCenter,
        children: [
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 20),
            child: SvgPicture.asset(
              'assets/svg/Logo full.svg',
              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
              height: 250,
              fit: BoxFit.fitHeight,
            ),
          ),
          SingleChildScrollView(
            physics: const AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics(),
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 300),
            child: DelayedDisplay(
              delay: const Duration(milliseconds: 400),
              fadingDuration: const Duration(milliseconds: 400),
              child: Material(
                color: Colors.white,
                borderRadius: const BorderRadius.only(
                  topRight: Radius.circular(40),
                  topLeft: Radius.circular(40),
                ),
                shadowColor: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.1),
                elevation: 5,
                clipBehavior: Clip.none,
                child: ListView.custom(
                  shrinkWrap: true,
                  primary: false,
                  clipBehavior: Clip.hardEdge,
                  physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                  childrenDelegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate(
                    addRepaintBoundaries: false,
                    addAutomaticKeepAlives: true,
                    childCount: pageitems.length,
                        (context, index) => pageitems[index],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Positioned(
            bottom: 0,
            left: 15,
            right: 15,
            child: Container(
              height: 2,
              color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.2),
            ), // the position from the right
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

Widget _svgOnTop(context) {
  return Padding(
    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 20, left: 20, right: 20),
    child: SvgPicture.asset(
      'assets/svg/Home/mountain.svg',
      color: const Color(0xff2C2513),
      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
      height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width/100 * 32.48 ,
      fit: BoxFit.fitWidth,
    ),
  );
}

Widget _horizontalScroller() {
  return SizedBox(
    height: 200,
    child: ListView.builder(
      //padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 20),
      scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
      itemCount: advBoxItems.length,
      physics:
          const BouncingScrollPhysics(parent: AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics()),
      primary: false,
      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
        return Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10),
          child: SizedBox(
            width: 200,
            child: Center(
              child: Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: [
                  SvgPicture.asset(
                    advBoxItems[index].svg,
                    fit: BoxFit.fitHeight,
                    height: 75,
                    width: 75,
                  ),
                  AutoSizeText(
                    advBoxItems[index].title,
                    textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                    maxLines: 1,
                    minFontSize: 20,
                    style: const TextStyle(
                      fontFamily: 'ArrialNarrow',
                      color: Color(0xff2C2513),
                    ),
                  ),
                  AutoSizeText(
                    advBoxItems[index].description,
                    textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                    maxLines: 3,
                    minFontSize: 14,
                    style: const TextStyle(
                      fontFamily: 'ArrialNarrow',
                      color: Color(0xff2C2513),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        );
      },
    ),
  );
}

Widget _gallerySwiper(context) {
  return Padding(
    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 40),
    child: SizedBox(
      height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 16 * 8,
      child: Swiper(
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
          final image = homePageImgs[index];
          return ClipRRect(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0),
            child: Image.asset(
              image,
              fit: BoxFit.fill,
            ),
          );
        },
        itemCount: 3,
        viewportFraction: 0.8,
        scale: 0.9,
      ),
    ),
  );
}

Widget _allLinksBox(context) {
  return Padding(
    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 100, left: 20, right: 20),
    child: Row(mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center, children: [
      _smallLinkBlock(context, 'РЕСТОРАН DEREZA', 'https://derezarest.ru/'),
      const SizedBox(
        width: 10,
      ),
      _smallLinkBlock(context, 'НАШ ИНТЕРНЕТ МАГАЗИН',
          'https://kozanostrashop.ru/shop/syry'),
    ]),
  );
}

Widget _smallLinkBlock(context, text, link) {
  return Container(
    height: 120,
    width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 2 - 25,
    decoration: BoxDecoration(
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30),
      color: Colors.white,
      border: Border.all(width: 2, color: const Color(0xFFAD8A6E)),
    ),
    child: Column(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
      children: [
        Expanded(
          child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10),
            child: Center(
              child: AutoSizeText(
                text,
                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                maxLines: 2,
                minFontSize: 18,
                style: const TextStyle(
                  fontFamily: 'Quadrata',
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
        Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 10),
          child: ElevatedButton(
            style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                elevation: 0,
                backgroundColor: const Color(0xff2C2513),
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                    left: 30, right: 30, bottom: 10, top: 10),
                shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(40))),
            child: const AutoSizeText(
              'ПЕРЕЙТИ',
              maxLines: 1,
              minFontSize: 18,
              style: TextStyle(
                fontFamily: 'ArialNarrow',
              ),
            ),
            onPressed: () {
              launchUrl(Uri.parse(link));
              HapticFeedback.lightImpact();
            },
          ),
        ),
      ],
    ),
  );
}

Widget _textBlock(text, padding) {
  return Padding(
    padding: padding,
    child: Text(
      text,
      style: const TextStyle(
        fontFamily: 'ArialNarrow',
        fontSize: 16,
        color: Color(0xff2C2513),
      ),
    ),
  );
}

Widget _wideBlock(text, description, svg, decoration, context) {
  return Padding(
    padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20, vertical: 30),
    child: Hero(
    tag: text,
    child: Container(
      height: 150,
      width: double.infinity,
      decoration: decoration,
      child: Material(
      color: decoration.color,
      borderRadius: const BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(30)),
      child: Row(
        children: [
          Expanded(
            flex: 1,
            child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 20, top: 20, bottom: 20),
              child: SvgPicture.asset(
                svg,
                fit: BoxFit.contain,
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Expanded(
            flex: 2,
            child: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
              children: [
                const SizedBox(
                  height: 15,
                ),
                AutoSizeText(
                  text,
                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                  maxLines: 1,
                  minFontSize: 18,
                  style: const TextStyle(
                    fontFamily: 'Quadrata',
                    color: Color(0xff2C2513),
                  ),
                ),
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 25),
                  child: AutoSizeText(
                    description,
                    textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                    maxLines: 2,
                    minFontSize: 16,
                    style: const TextStyle(
                      fontFamily: 'ArialNarrow',
                      color: Color(0xff2C2513),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 10),
                  child: ElevatedButton(
                    style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                        elevation: 0,
                        backgroundColor: const Color(0xff2C2513),
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                            left: 30, right: 30, bottom: 10, top: 10),
                        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(40))),
                    child: const AutoSizeText(
                      'ПОДРОБНЕЕ',
                      maxLines: 1,
                      minFontSize: 18,
                      style: TextStyle(
                        fontFamily: 'ArialNarrow',
                      ),
                    ),
                    onPressed: () {
                      Navigator.push(
                        context,
                        PageRouteBuilder(
                          transitionDuration:
                          const Duration(milliseconds: 300),
                          pageBuilder: (_, __, ___) =>
                              _awardsHero(text, context),
                        ),
                      );
                    },
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ),
    ),
    ),
  );
}



Widget _awardsHero(tag, context) {
return Hero(
tag: tag,
child: const Scaffold(
  backgroundColor: Colors.white,
),
);
}
```

All your advice and ideas will be very appreciated, please help me to make this scollview perfect

Comment: Figured out that applying color to mountain.svg is a bad idea, and now listview is a little faster

Comment: I think the problem with SVG already answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66872237/10294178. Anyway you could try using Flutter 3, I migrated my projects to Flutter 3, and the list rendering performance is so much better

Comment: Already on 3.3.2, but I am new to flutter, so I am just looking for some usefull hints